# VB - How to obtain category color for Outlook AppointmentItem

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

First time here...

I'm editing OlCalndr.dot macros (import Outlook Calendar info into Word) and trying to grab the category color for each appointment.

I have the AppointmentItem object, and appt.Categories will return a String of the categories this appointment has.  However, I can't figure out how to get the category color.

Grateful for any help...

cheers,

David

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually look up the category name into the categories catalog from the Namespace.

1. Obtain the string of categories from the AppointmentItem.Categories
2. Split (on ','). Find the first Name.
3. Obtain the full collection of available categories from [Application.Session.Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176422%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
4. Enumerate through the categories until you find the one with the name from step (2).
5. This category will have a [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174986%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (from the [olCategoryColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208064%28v=office.12%29.aspx) enumeration).